# I want to execute a select query in "then" clause . which is have highlighted

Tags: sql, oracle10g

```
update demo_hr_data set login = (case 
when (select count(*) from demo_hr_data where login like SUBSTR('john',0,1)||'doe'||'%') > 0 then SUBSTR('john',0,1)||'doe'||
    -- HERE --
    select count(*) from demo_hr_data where login like SUBSTR('john',0,1)||'doe'||'%'
else 'jdoe'
end)
where fname = 'john' and lname = 'doe';
```

Comment: i am getting missing expression error.

Comment: Your question isnt clear. Tell us what you want to do. Show us sample data and desire output. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I need to update "login" using firstname and lastname. login should be constructed using 1st alphabet of fname and appended with last name. it has cases, if the login is present , it should append a sequence number. and increment the number if necessary. like if jdoe , jdoe1 is present next login created should be jdoe2.

Comment: Please edit your question to be clear instead of adding comments.

Comment: You are missing a left paren at -- HERE --.

Answer (score 0):

```
update demo_hr_data set login = (case 
when (select count(*) from demo_hr_data where login like SUBSTR('john',0,1)||'doe'||'%') > 0 then SUBSTR('john',0,1)||'doe'||
    (select to_char(count(*)) from demo_hr_data where login like SUBSTR('john',0,1))||'doe'||'%'
else 'jdoe'
end) 
where fname = 'john' and lname = 'doe';
```

try this... it worked for me